# How do I iterate through floating point numbers in python?

Tags: python

How do I iterate through floating point numbers in python?

```
for i in range(1,10,0.001):
    print(i)
```

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: What is your desired output based on the code you've shown?

Comment: @metatoaster well, i want it to add increment 0.001.

Comment: `range` can't be a float.  `numpy.arange` allows it, but use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

One option:

```
for i in range(1000,10000):
    print(i/1000)
```

Comment: you shoud use  `i / 1000` or `i * 0.001`

Comment: @furas `i * 0.001` is bad. For example `1001 / 1000` is `1.001` while  `1001 * 0.001` is `1.0010000000000001`.

Comment: Or `for i in (j*0.001 for j in range(1000, 10000):`

Comment: Thanks, fixed using numpy         for i in np.arange(0,10,0.1):